# Change row class of table based on value of cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Is it possible to change row class (using bootstrap) based of value of data cell?
Something like this:
(here I hard coded class into row) 
[image]

Here is fragment of code

```
 onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties) {
      var content = "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'>" + "<tr><th>Šifra trafostanice</th><td>" + feature.properties.ts_sifra + 
      "</td></tr>" + "<tr><th>Name</th><td>" + feature.properties.ts_naziv + "</td></tr>" +  
      "<tr><th>Code</th><td>" + feature.properties.sifra_lampe + "</td></tr>" +
      "<tr><th>Power</th><td>" + feature.properties.tip_lampe + "</td></tr>" +
      "<tr><th>Pole type</th><td>" + feature.properties.vrsta_stupa + "</td></tr>" +
      "<tr><th>Adress</th><td>" + feature.properties.adresa + "</td></tr>" +
      "<tr><th>Services</th><td>" + feature.properties.datum + "</td></tr>" 
      "</table>";.....
```

Using code above i get something like this:
[image]

So, my question is is it possible to change class of row based of data value?

> (Example if value of table row Services is 'Nema servisa' add class
>   success else leave row unchanged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are generating this via JavaScript yes this is very doable.

On that row just check to see if `feature.properties.datum === 'Nema Servisa'`. If yes, add `class="success"`. If not, don't.

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
   if (feature.properties) {
     var content = "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'>" + "<tr><th>Šifra trafostanice</th><td>" + feature.properties.ts_sifra + 
     "</td></tr>" + "<tr><th>Name</th><td>" + feature.properties.ts_naziv + "</td></tr>" +  
     "<tr><th>Code</th><td>" + feature.properties.sifra_lampe + "</td></tr>" +
     "<tr><th>Power</th><td>" + feature.properties.tip_lampe + "</td></tr>" +
     "<tr><th>Pole type</th><td>" + feature.properties.vrsta_stupa + "</td></tr>" +
     "<tr><th>Adress</th><td>" + feature.properties.adresa + "</td></tr>" +
     "<tr" + (feature.properties.datum === 'Nema servisa' ? ' class="success"' : '') + "><th>Services</th><td>" + feature.properties.datum + "</td></tr>" 
     "</table>";.....
```

Comment: Yes that valid, neat answer, thx! I even tweaked a bit adding this line of code      feature.properties.datum === 'Nema servisa' ? ' class="danger"' : '' || feature.properties.datum != 'Nema servisa' ? ' class="success"' : ''

Answer (score 1):

When creating the table, add a `class="feature-property"` to each td element.
Then you can define this function and call it after the table is generated:

```
function highlightTableRow(match){
    $('.feature-property').each(function(){
        var value = $(this).html();
        if(value === match){
            $(this).addClass('success');  
        }
    });   
}
```

And `match` would be the data value you want to check.. in this case, `Nema Servisa`

Comment: Thx for answer as well! :)